# Powershell equivalent of Bash "Alternate Value"

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, parameter-expansion

I'm trying to call a command in a Powershell script that has optional switches, and it must dynamically determine whether to include the switches.

In Bash, you can do something like this (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306739/how-to-not-pass-empty-quoted-variables-as-arguments-to-commands)):

```
curl -o - ${PARAMS:+"--data" "$PARAMS"}
```

So it will only include the `--data` switch and argument if `PARAMS` is defined. Is there an equivalent to this in Powershell?

Comment: Is this your _actual use case_ or just a made up example? PowerShell doesn't have inline variable modification the way bash does, but it has a number of _other_ facilities for conditionally passing/proxying args. Whether they'd solve your problem depends a bit on the context. Are you only passing `[string]` arguments? Is the target command always a binary/executable, or is it a PowerShell command/cmdlet/function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mathias states, **PowerShell has *no* direct equivalent to Bash's [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)**. Possibly bringing a similar feature to PowerShell in the future is discussed in [Github issue #9566](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9566).

**If you're calling an *external program*** such as `curl`<sup>[1]</sup> (rather than a PowerShell cmdlet/script/function), you can use the following approach:

```
curl -o - $(if ($PARAMS) { '--data', $PARAMS })
```

This takes advantage of the following behaviors:

- The ability to pass the output from arbitrary statements as command arguments, using `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--); note that for simple *expressions* and *commands* just `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--) is sufficient.

  - If such a `$(...)` or `(...)` argument produces *no output* (is effectively `$null`), *no argument* is passed when calling *external programs*; in the case at hand, this applies if the `if ($PARAMS)` conditional evaluates to `$false`, i.e. if `$PARAMS` is "falsy", based on [PowerShell's to-Boolean coercion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53108138/45375).
  - Note: If `$PARAMS` can contain a non-string value such as `0` that would also be considered `$false`, use a more explicit conditional: `if ($null -ne $PARAMS)`, which is only `$true` if `$PARAMS` is *undefined* (or explicitly contains `$null`).
- *Arrays* passed as arguments to *external programs* result in the array elements being passed as *individual arguments*.

---

Note that **different rules apply when calling PowerShell-native commands** (cmdlets, scripts, functions):

- Arrays are considered *single* arguments that are passed *as a whole*.
- You cannot pass parameter *names* (e.g., `-Body`) via variables or expressions.

The solution to both problems is to **use [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)**:

This involves first storing the dynamic arguments in a *variable*, which is then passed via `@` rather than `$` (e.g., define a variable `$dynArgs` and pass it as `@dynArgs`), and it comes in two flavors:

- To pass *positional* (unnamed) arguments dynamically, define the splatting variable as an *array* (e.g. `$dynArgs = 'foo', 'bar'`)
- To pass *named* arguments (arguments preceded by their target parameter name) dynamically, define the splatting variable as a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables).

Therefore, if you were to invoke [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) instead of `curl`, for instance, and you wanted to conditionally pass a `-Body` argument, you would do something like the following:

```sh
$dynArgs = @{} # Initialize a hashtable

# Conditionally create a 'Body' entry. The key name
# must match the target parameter (without "-"):
if ($PARAMS) { $dynArgs['Body'] = $PARAMS }

# Pass $dynArgs via *splatting* - note the "@" sigil.
# If the hashtable is empty, nothing is passed.
# Splatting can be *combined* with directly passed arguments
# (symbolized by "..." here).
Invoke-RestMethod @dynArgs ...
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that in *Windows PowerShell* `curl` is (unfortunately) a built-in alias for the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) cmdlet, which *shadows* the external `curl.exe` utility that now comes with Windows. However, by using `curl.exe` for invocation (i.e. by explicitly including the filename extension), the alias can be bypassed.</sup>